# Ruby GEM for File and Directory manipulation

Tags: ruby, rubygems

i'm looking for gem(s) which will provide me tools for File and Directory manipulation.

Basicly i would like to get possibility to:

- search file in provided directory
- search pattern inside file (different extensions)
- insert into file at precise place content

I know how to do it using Ruby, but it would be nice to get such gem :)

Thanks

Comment: I'm a little confused as to why you'd need a gem for this.  You should be able to do the searching using Dir.glob, and you can insert something into a file by opening the file in a+ mode.  Am I just misunderstanding?

Comment: Hello, "I know how to do it using Ruby, but it would be nice to get such gem :)" I also can parse command line arguments by hand... but i rather use Thor ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Anwser is NO, there isn't one.